# Python Netifaces Network Usage

Tags: python, psutil

Apologies in advance if this is a dumb question as I am new to programming.

I have a simple piece of code like this which shows me a list of network interface addresses and their information,

```
import neitfaces
print(netifaces.interfaces())
user_input = input('Address: ')
print(netifaces.ifaddresses(user_input))
```

But how do I get the total number of the usage (bytes sent and received) of network interfaces on the computer?

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with neitfaces, however, I did a quick google and found some example code that might be of use [recieve bytes example](http://www.programcreek.com/python/example/81895/netifaces.interfaces).

I also made a sample script your that should work logically, however I did not test it. You need to install the [psutil package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil).

```
import neitfaces
import psutil

print(netifaces.interfaces())
user_input = input('Address: ')

x = netifaces.ifaddresses(user_input)

data = psutil.net_io_counters(pernic=True)
data = data[x] if type(data) == dict else data
i.rx, i.tx = data[0], data[1]

print(i.rx)
print(i.tx)
```

This should get you going in the right direction.

Marc

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try but do I need to specify which network interface to grab the bytes sent and out information?

Comment: Thanks but when I run the module, I get invalid syntax. The blinking cursor is just after the double quote {1}" on the last line

Comment: @Litherz right, you're using python3 so change that print statement to print(i.rx)

Comment: The module runs and I have entered the network interface address but now I get this red line error, data = data[x] if type(data) == dict else data
KeyError: None